# Spark Pipe example

Tags: scala, streaming, pipe, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and trying to figure out how the pipe method works.  I have the following code in Scala

```
sc.textFile(hdfsLocation).pipe("preprocess.py").saveAsTextFile(hdfsPreprocessedLocation)
```

The values hdfsLocation and hdfsPreprocessedLocation are fine.  As proof, the following code works from the command line

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfsLocation/* | ./preprocess.py | head
```

When I run the above Spark code I get the following errors

```
14/11/25 09:41:50 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "preprocess.py": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD.compute(PipedRDD.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
... 12 more
```

In order to solve this for Hadoop streaming I would just use the --files attribute, so I tried the same thing for Spark.  I start Spark with the following command

```
bin/spark-shell --files ./preprocess.py
```

but that gave the same error.

I couldn't find a good example of using Spark with an external process via pipe, so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give me the preprocess.py? I need some example of pipe.Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer, so I won't finalize this, but it appears that the file paths are different when running spark in local and cluster mode.  When running spark without --master the paths to the pipe command are relative to the local machine.  When running spark with --master the paths to the pipe command are ./

UPDATE:
This actually isn't correct.  I was using SparkFiles.get() to get the file name.  It turns out that when calling .pipe() on an RDD the command string is evaluated on the driver and then passed to the worker.  Because of this SparkFiles.get() is not the appropriate way to get the file name.  The file name should be ./ because SparkContext.addFile() should put that file on ./ relative to to where each worker is run from.  But I'm so sour on .pipe now that I've take .pipe out of my code in total in favor of .mapPartitions in combination of a PipeUtils object that I wrote [here](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/pull/772/files).  This is actually more efficient because I only have to incur the script startup costs once per partition instead of once per example.